# Spring - War file is not starting on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm using `spring boot` with  `jdk 1.8`. 
I'm deploying the war to `tomcat 8.5` locally on my machine and it starts and works as expected. 
When deploying the war to the server which uses `tomcat 7.0`
I get the following error

> SERVER: Unable to process Jar entry
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/core/support/ResourceMappingUtils.class]
>   from Jar [jar:file:....
>   /WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-rest-core-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar!]

My pom.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>webMavenNeo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-maven-neo4j</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <neo4j-ogm.version>3.0.0</neo4j-ogm.version>
        <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Kay-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
        <start-class>social.spring.data.neo4j.Main</start-class>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jsog</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's war not jar.?? If u r using spring-boot.. why are you messing yourself with tomcat and war deployment.?? I mean, create a jar, spring-boot comes with embedded tomcat, you only need to run jar file using `java -jar 'your_project.jar'`

Comment: Spring Boot 2.0 uses Spring 5, which requires Servlet API 3.1 at least. Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 container... See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What's-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x

Comment: @M.Deinum so using spring boot 1.5.9 release would solve the problem ?

Comment: Minimum requirement for Spring Boot 2.0 is Tomcat 8.5. It will not boot up on Tomcat 7. Use Spring Boot 1.5 instead.

Comment: I tried running the same project locally using `tomcat 7.0` and got the same error. 
So, I'll be using `spring 1.5 `.
Thanks for the effort guys.
This solved the problem.